# Is there a measure for how associative a binary operator is?

Tags: abstract-algebra, binary-operations, associativity

For some binary operation defined on a set, it is of interest whether the operation is associative or not (among, of course many other things).

Is there a measure (and accompanying theory) that describes the extent to which a binary operation is associative? For example, if this measure is $M$, then we could have $M(*, S) = 0$ if the $*$ defined on $S$ has 0 triplets $(a, b, c)$ for which $a * (b * c) = (a * b) * c$, and $M(*, S) = 1$ if the operation is associative (so for all triplets $a * (b * c) = (a * b) * c$). For operations where some triplets associate, we could assign a value between 0 and 1.

I wonder, for instance, how other properties will affect this measure. For example, a operation with identity has at least $7n + 1$ triplets which "associate" (with $n$ being the number of elements in the set $S$). A commutative operation will have even more.

I tried to do a Google search, but lacking any useful keywords I could not find anything.

---

**Background:** This question arose from [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2807156/how-can-i-prove-this-operation-on-domino-tilings-is-associative) where I asked for some help to prove that a particular operation is associative, where it turns out the operation is not associative at all. It surprised me for two reasons: I had some theoretical reasons (now proven to be wrong) to believe it, but also, in trying to get a proof I worked through several examples that where triplets *were* associating.

Comment: not sure this is exactly what you want but https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associator

Comment: Not quite be very related, thanks!

Comment: One could make such a measure out of the associator by taking the number of triples for which the associator equals one and dividing by $n^3$.  I don't know if this would make for a useful measure, but it might lead to some insights.

Comment: Yes, I was wondering if there is some existing work on this. If I cannot find anything I may look at it a bit on my own.